# Event.type not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: jquery

By referring this [**link**](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/), I had adopted a property called `Event.Type` to my `script` for a particular need and it worked fine in `IE9`. After that while making `compatibility test`, i came to know that it is not working in `Mozilla FireFox`. Additionally it is working with out any problems in `Google Chrome` and `Safari`.

### [*DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/Kjk7a/)

Any clues to solve this ? or Is there any alernate way available to substitute `Event.Type` in jquery.?

Comment: You need to pass the `event` to the function - http://jsfiddle.net/Kjk7a/3/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're question is, but you forgot to pass the event to the `load()` handling function: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Kjk7a/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most common browsers the `event` object is defined globally, so it is available within the scope of your `load` handler. However, in Firefox the `event` object is not defined globally, and the error `ReferenceError: event is not defined` is returned (use `Ctrl+Shift+J` to get the errors console if Firefox).

As the comments to your question suggest, the best practice is to pass the `event` object to the handler function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(window).load(function(event){ alert(event.type); }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what i have done ; The idea is to pass the `event` varibale down to inside function code. example

```
var load = function(){
        var output = document.getElementById('preview');
        output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

Then now instead i listend to the oncHange event like this :

```
 //passing the event varible along inside ,,this might work on chorme 
 //without passing events but not in firefox and now fixed!!

$( "#uploadBtn" ).change(function(event) {
        var output = document.getElementById('preview');
        output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
      });
```